# Asp.net - adding function to class

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop

I have a code-first Entity Framework class that looks like this:

```
public class Image
{
    public int ImageID { get; set; }
    public string DataType { get; set; }
    public int Size { get; set; }
    public byte[] Content { get; set; }
}
```

I have written several lines of code in a controller that receives a IFormFile and then extracts the file data and reads it into an Image:

```
var content = formFile.OpenReadStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[content.Length];
content.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
var newImg = new Image();
newImg.Content = buf;
newImg.DataType = formFile.ContentType;
```

Since this code is re-used wherever an image is being uploaded, I would like to somehow encapsulate it as a 'SaveUpload' function. It will be used in various controllers across the solution.

Is the best way to add this as a {set;} only non-mapped property to the Image class/table?

Or do I somehow encapsulate or inherit this property (sorry, I am still learning OOP terms)?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider creating an UploadService class to encapsulate this logic.  Neither the controller(s), nor the Image class should really be aware of these details and by abstracting it into a service you will likely find that the code is more readable and easier to maintain.

UploadService:

```
public class UploadService
{
    public void SaveUpload(IFormFile formFile)
    {
        var content = formFile.OpenReadStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[content.Length];
        content.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        var newImg = new Image();
        newImg.Content = buf;
        newImg.DataType = formFile.ContentType;

        //insert newImg...
    }
}
```

I would even consider taking it one step further by injecting this service into your controllers using a dependency injection framework like Unity or Ninject, which will allow you to isolate the service for unit testing.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like

```
public class Image
{
     public int ImageID { get; set; }
     public string DataType { get; set; }
     public int Size { get; set; }
     public byte[] Content { get; set; 

     public static Image SaveUpload(IFormFile formFile) {
        var newImage = new Image();
        var content = formFile.OpenReadStream();
        byte[] buf = new byte[content.Length];
        content.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
        var newImg = new Image();
        newImg.Content = buf;
        newImg.DataType = formFile.ContentType;
        return newImage;
    }
}
```

Save with

```
 var image = Image.SaveUpload(formFile);
```

Answer (score 0):

Inside your class do next step:

```
public static void YourMethod(/*parameters, if you need them*/){
    var content = formFile.OpenReadStream();
    byte[] buf = new byte[content.Length];
    content.Read(buf, 0, buf.Length);
    var newImg = new Image();
    newImg.Content = buf;
    newImg.DataType = formFile.ContentType;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if it can be that simple. Is that bad practice since it means this logic is in the same class which defines the database schema?

Comment: @DaveDickson No. You may create another class for this function. For example, you may have a class UTILS.cs, where you will have this function. You also may create dll library, if you need a highest security. It depends on you.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to add normal static function, but for good practic: POCO class should't have any logic expect fields. Better way is to create other class, f.e: `UploadService` which method: `Save(Image image)`. **Your choice.**